# Show number of events for the every user just after the user name in 1st panel

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I have 2 panels in 'timeline' full-calendar, 1st panel showing users and 2nd panel showing all the events but now I want to show number of events(in bold) also for the every user just after the user name in 1st panel. How can I achieve this? Help is highly appreciated.

Sample Code :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'timelineYear',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
    },
    resources: getJSonObject(jsonUser),
    events: getJSonObject(jsonEvent),
});
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest downloading the number of total events as an extra property in your resources JSON, and then using [resourceRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/resourceRender) to add that info to the rendered HTML of the resource. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: resourceRender: function (UserJSON, $td) {
                    $td.eq(0).find('.fc-cell-content').append($('<strong style="float: right;"><span>2</span></strong>'));                    
                },

Comment: Ok. So I'm guessing that code adds something to the resource cell? But you need it to read some data from the resource object - that's the next step. Are you stuck? You just gave some code without explaining your current problem!

Comment: @ADyson, it worked, I just need to send count in resource json and pass it inside span. Thanks brother.

Comment: That's great. You should post a proper answer below, if you solved it. Then people can vote on it, and others with a similar issue can find it in search results :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem using resorceRender. Just send json from controller and pass it to resourcejson in fullcalender

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                displayEventTime: false,   
 
                defaultView: 'timelineYear',
 
                header: {
 
                    left: 'prev,next',
 
                    center: 'title',
 
                },
 
                resources: getJSonObject(users),
 
                resourceRender: function (users, $td) {  
                    $td.find('.fc-cell-text').append($('**'+users.count+'**'));
 
                },
 
                events: getJSonObject(events),
 
});